# How to add android target / API android-26 in android studio?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new in android development tools and I'm about to try cordova to develop android app using web technologies, but when i use the comand cordova requirements the result is this

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Please install Android target / API level: "android-26".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: "C:\Users\json\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat"
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for API level android-26
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle
```

When i installed the android studio the default API is android-27 and i dont know how to add android-26 API. Please help.

Comment: @Michael the error tell me run C:\Users\json\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat but when i run its says android command depreciated so the instruction is wrong
btw i look at here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html first

Comment: and its says "If you're using Android Studio, then you do not need to use this tool and you can instead manage your SDK packages from the IDE" so i thought i should do it on android studio, but i tried the command on that link and not try on the android studio and its now downlaoding

Comment: Then either run `SDK Manager.exe`, or launch it from the IDE.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Android Studio on macOS has platform settings at Preferences... > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Platform tab.  Checking Android 8.0 (Oreo) having the API level 26 and clicking Apply installed the package and now the requirements check passes as follows:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26
Gradle: installed /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle
```

Hope this works on Windows as well.

Answer (score 10):

Another option from the terminal:

go to: "C:\Users\YOU-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin"

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
```

as listed here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

Comment: This word for me. I have used android studio to install SDK, but still failed. I use sdkmanager commad before it is success.

Answer (score 1):

If using Ionic Cordova(Ionic 3), the plugin:`cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` now includes the Android target when installed.

in config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.2.0">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
```

in package.json:

```
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
  }
```

When adding android platform:

```
> cordova platform add android --save
  Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.1.1
  Adding android project...
  Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms\android
    Package: com.packageName.projectName
    Name: Project Name
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-27
```