# Ionic Android UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning strings.xml

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Angular and ionic 3.19.1. Whenever I try to run on an android device, I get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml'

What does this mean and how can it be solved?

Comment: Quick googling yields this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13702 Have you checked this issue already?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. 
It seems the version of android SDK is the issue.
You need to install Android 8.0 (Oreo) having the API level 26 
  Please refer this [How to add android target / API android-26 in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059674/how-to-add-android-target-api-android-26-in-android-studio#)

Once sdk was installed , while building android app, I had to correct the JDK path as my JAVA_HOME was pointing to JRE instead of JDK.
Another issue came up was related to insufficient memory. I had to create a new environment variable "_java_options"
the value for that is givens as "-Xmx512M"

Now the build works fine.

Thank you